# Python Encryption

Tags: python, encryption

So for an exam question I've followed this specific pseudo code which basically makes a program which encrypts a number sequence using the same principle as the ceasar cipher. It should work but for some reason it returns the error.

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Heres the code, i hope you guys can help me, much appreciated

```
plainNum = input("enter a number to encode ") 
codedNum = ' '
Key = input("enter a key ")

for i in plainNum:
    codedNum = codedNum + str((int(i)+key)%10)
    print codedNum
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `raw_input` if you expect a string:

```
plainNum = raw_input("enter a number to encode ")
```

`input()` interprets the input as if it is Python code; enter `5` and it'll return an integer, enter `'some text'` (with quotes) and it'll return a string. `raw_input()` on the other hand returns the entered input uninterpreted.

Comment: Im not though :) i want the user to enter a number, or doesn't it matter should i just change them both to raw_input? thanks

Comment: @user1655562: You are interpreting the number as a series of digits; that is a string, *not* a python integer value.

Comment: @user1655562: Your key on the other hand, you are using as a integer, so there `input()` makes *some* sense, but you could force it to only accept integers by using `int(raw_input('...'))`.

Comment: Cheers dude its working now haha! I had a complete mind block for why is wasn't working

Comment: @user1655562: It's possible that you got confused by reading some documentation meant for Python 3. In 3.0 and later, `input` always returns a string, and there is no `raw_input`; in 2.7 and earlier, `input` tries to evaluate the input, and you need `raw_input` to get a string.

Comment: Yeh im using python 2.7 but i have both versions on my computer so sometimes i get confused :S

Answer (score 2):

Most dirty fix of all, simply change

```
for i in plainNum:
```

with

```
for i in str(plainNum):
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working but not if I use a decimal and it doesn't behave if I enter words or spaces.  Consider checking first that the entry is a number with something like:

```
try:
    float(element)
except ValueError:
    print "Not a float"
```

after stripping any whitespace with something like:

```
plainNum = plainNum.strip()
```

But this outputs the encoded digits of your entered integer:

```
plainNum = raw_input("enter a number to encode ") 
codedNum = ' '
key = input("enter a key ")

for i in plainNum:
    codedNum = codedNum + str((int(i)+key)%10)
    print codedNum
```

Ask the user for the number with raw_input.  This makes the input a string which you can iterate over with:

```
for char in plainNum:
```

Yes, this is a now a char in a string and so you've used the int(i) function.

Comment: i would use data validation but this is for the specific purpose of an exam paper and this question is when you have to turn the pseudo code directly into the language you know, so we can't change it or optimise is other wise we lose marks on the real exam, this is just practise at the moment

Comment: Yes, also in the working example I posted above I had to change Key to key.
And I would change the for i in plainNum: to for char in plainNum: for the style points.

Comment: Oh yeh i understand what you mean now

Answer (score 0):

you maybe also wanna change key to Key to reflect what variable is declared
and also make codeNum initially equal to '' instead of ' ' (no space vs space)
just book keeping stuff